# Hyperplane in the first dimension?

Tags: linear-algebra

If a hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is of dimension *n-1*, what is the geometric interpretation of a hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^1$? Is it a point?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: rschwieb is right. One further remark though. In some contexts (e.g. linear algebra as opposed to affine geometry) the hyperplanes in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are only those passing through the origin. In those contexts there is only one hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^1$ and it is the origin itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Vincent stated in the comments, since your question have linear-algebra as a tag, an hyperplane of $\mathbb R^1$ is not only **a** point, but **the** point passing through the origin. Which is, well, the origin.

It make sens, as if you see it in a vector space point of view, it's a 0-dimentional vector space. And the only one we know is $\{0\}$

Comment: This raises the question of what a hyperplane is in the space $\{0\}.$ I'm guessing textbooks are sufficiently careful to make it explicit that the definition only applies to vector spaces having dimension greater than $0$ (don't have time now to look at any), but I notice that the [Wikipedia article doesn't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I did a quick check on *Linear Algebra done right* by S.Axler. Sadly it's the only linear algebra book I have with me and it doesn't deal with hyperplanes (at least I didn't find it, we don't have a CTRL+f function on paper books).